# how to differentiate an indicator function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm reading [this paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/ECML2011LinkPrediction.pdf) and I arrived at this part when they introduce a formula for what they call 'an indicator function'. Here is a shot:

[image]

what I understood from the first two formulas is that I need to minimize the number of ones. However I got confused in the third equation when they have the form $l(w^T(x_i-x_j), 1)$. What does it mean? And how can I differentiate such a function?!!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you don't differentiate an indicator function. An indicator function is not smooth: it jumps at certain values in the domain. The authors of this paper recognize this fact, so they replace the indicator function $\mathbf{1}[\cdot]$ with a **regularized loss function** $l(\cdot)$.

Regularization is a broad term that can mean many things, but one kind of regularization is to take a quantized signal and attempt to find a smooth (i.e. differentiable) approximation to the curve. Many regularization approaches exist; from the snippet posted, it is not clear immediately which approach was chosen.

The regularized signal is presumed to be "close enough" to what we want to minimize -- the indicator function. But it has the benefit of having a gradient, hence we can use it to solve our optimization problem.

Comment: would a square-loss function work? I think this is what i understood from the paper. But using the square-loss then won't take the 1 into account.

Comment: The regularization approach taken is described in the first few pages of the paper.

Comment: I think the idea here is mainly about the loss function and not regularization

Comment: It's about both; the loss function alone is insufficient. The regularization is necessary to penalize a loss model that improperly approximates the error. One such example is Tikhonov regularization, which is explained really well here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization

Comment: I'm still stuck at understanding this equation $l(w^T(x_i-x_j), 1)$. How would you *read* it? Does it mean that if $w^T(x_i-x_j)>0$ then it should give a 1, and if it's less than zero then it should give the result?

Comment: The sum of an indicator function looks like a staircase. A smooth approximation to a staircase looks like a handicap ramp. More or less...